# SSIS Package - Configure Format Version Programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis, ezapi

I have developed a custom application which is able to generate SSIS Packages automatically based on some settings which are stored internally in the application.

This package used to have PackageFormatVersion (6), which is compatible with(from) SQL Server (2012).

Recently, I upgraded the EzApi version to the latest one (v0.8.9) and the exported package now has been changed to PackageFormatVersion (8), which is compatible with(from) SQL Server (2014).

Is there any way to configure this PackageFormatVersion property programmatically in C# and continue exporting packages for SQL Server (2012) with this newest EzApi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that within your project since EzApi.dll relies on DTSRuntime dll and DTSPipline.dll assemblies which are related to a specific SQL Server version since they are installed from SQL Server Installation (Client SDK).

Only way to do that is to open the EzApi source code, change the referenced Assemblies (mentioned above) to the SQL Server 2012 version and make sure that all classes doesn't contains errors. Then you have to rebuild the EzApi library and use it.

---

*Note that I have done this one time since I was looking to use EzApi to create SQL Server 2014 packages.*

Comment: you are correct, each EzApi is targeting on specific SQL Server version.

For this reason, I have different forked editions of the EzApi.

https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2012EzApi, https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2014EzApi, https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2016EzApi

In general, we could create one higher level, including all related assemblies and providing the target choice but this may complicate things.